# Auto mapper fails when updating existing object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

I am using Auto Mapper to map ViewModel to Domain Model. 
In that there is one property which is string in ViewModel and Nullable Datetime in Domain Model. 
When I use AutoMapper to convert ViewModel object to new DomainModel object it converts properly, 
 
But if I pass existing DomainModel object where datetime property is already filled, Automapper gives below error.

```
Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Func`4[System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], AutoMapper.ResolutionContext, System.DateTime]' 
 to type 'System.Func`4[System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], AutoMapper.ResolutionContext, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]'.
```

I Want to Update Existing object with new values from ViewModel. 
 
e.g. Code

```
public class SalaryDetailsViewModel
{
    public string EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}

public class SalaryDetails
{
    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapperCode -

```
CreateMap<SalaryDetails, SalaryDetailsViewModel>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<string, DateTime?>().ConvertUsing(new NullableDateTimeConverterForString());
CreateMap<DateTime?, string>().ConvertUsing(new StringFromNullableDateTime());

public class StringFromNullableDateTime : ITypeConverter<DateTime?, string>
    {
        public string Convert(DateTime? source, string destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return source.ConvertDateTimeToString();
        }
    }

public class NullableDateTimeConverterForString : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime?>
    {
        public DateTime? Convert(string source, DateTime? destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return source.ConvertStringToNullableDateTime();
        }
    }
```

DateTime Related Helper Methods -

```
public static DateTime? ConvertStringToNullableDateTime(this string dateTimeValue, string format = "dd/MM/yyyy")
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeValue, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                out var dtConvertedValue))
            {
                return dtConvertedValue;
            }
            return null;
        }

public static string ConvertDateTimeToString(this DateTime? dateTimeValue, string format = "dd/MM/yyyy")
        {
            return dateTimeValue.HasValue ? dateTimeValue.Value.ConvertDateTimeToString() : "";
        }
```

Working Code Example -

```
var salaryDetails = _mapper.Map<SalaryDetails>(new SalaryDetailsViewModel() { EffectiveDate = "01/01/2020" });
```

Error Code

```
var salaryDetailsExisitng = new SalaryDetails() { EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now };
salaryDetailsExisitng = _mapper.Map(new SalaryDetailsViewModel() { EffectiveDate = "10/01/2020" }, salaryExisitng);
```

Ideally it should have updated new effective date from ViewModel.

Comment: Your code works for me. Upgrade AM.

Comment: Which version of AM you're using? I'm using 9.0.0

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages. So could not update more than AM V9.0.0

Comment: @ArjavDave - what change are you suggesting only removing assignee variable, I dont see any impact of change happening there. Error still exists.

Comment: @DaxeshVora you code [runs just fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RLGCyS) (with small tweaks to make it compile)

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @GuruStron what tweak did you make to make it run?

Comment: @DaxeshVora `dateTimeValue.Value.ConvertDateTimeToString()` => `dateTimeValue.Value.ToString(format)` in `ConvertDateTimeToString` and in last line(in your error code in question) `salaryExisitng` -> `salaryDetailsExisitng ` cause in your post `salaryExisitng` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. Finally was able to solve issue, issue was due to SalaryDetailsViewModel part of another viewmodel and that viewmodel was also having its own mapping convfiguration. So I had to set SalaryDetailsViewModel mapping configuration before its parent viewmodel.